# Two or more drawables in One State in Android Selector

Tags: android, xml, selector, drawable

Is it possible to have two or more drawables used in one state of a selector? How to do it?

I asked this question because I can't any resource that answers this.

**PROBLEM**

I have trouble in attaching two drawables. This question is also related to [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504430/change-margin-of-a-layout-using-xml-in-layer-list) one I asked previously.

My problem is basically editing the margin of the linear layout and changing the format of the linear layout using layer-list.

Comment: Well, you can set the `background` and the `src` (e.g. foreground) resources there, but what do you need these for?

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList

Comment: I read that already but didn't solve my problem. Anyhow, thanks!

Comment: and your problem actually is ...?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504430/change-margin-of-a-layout-using-xml-in-layer-list

Comment: Drawables have nothing to do with margins, they are totally different creatures

Comment: Is it possible to change the size of the margin of a shape via xml or using the layer-list as asked in another question?

Comment: no, you cannot do that in xml, do it in runtime